# How does this for loop and dictionary work? - Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got some code from this site which I've amended slightly for my needs. It takes a sentence, and displays the positions of the words in list 'l'. I know basically how it works, but I'm stumped on some of the detail and was hoping someone could explain it to me in VERY layman terms...

Here's the code:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence to analyse: ")   
splitted = sentence.split()
dictionary = {}
l=[]

for i,j in enumerate(splitted):
    if j in dictionary:
        l.append(dictionary[j] + 1)

    else:
        dictionary[j]=i
        l.append(i + 1)

print (l)
```

Here are the things I don't currently get/not sure of:

1 - The two variables i and j - do these go through the list and assign a key (the word?) and a value (position)? I can see by printing the dictionary that it's assigning a positional number to each word. Is this what's happening?

2 - Which part of the code is responsible for populating the dictionary with the words from the list? Using the print command I can see this happens in the 'if' statement but I can't get my head around how it happens. I can see how the information from the dictionary goes into list 'l'.

3 - The 'else statement looks like it assigns any duplicated words the number and adds them to the list 'l', but as above I can't quite get my head around how this works.

I've been trying to trace the route of a word in the splitter list through the code but can't quite get it so any help to aid my understanding would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. The 'splitted' list contains all the words of the entered sentences like ['Hello', 'Python'], if you iterate over that list using enumerate you will obtain this: i=0, j="hello" for the first iteration and i=1, j="Python" for the seconds one. 2/3. in the else condition dictionary[j] is the part of the code where the dictionary is populated. where "j" represent a word and "i" the iteration number: so the last position of the word in the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The enumerate function in this context returns an index and a word. So, `i` has values such as 1,2,3,4... and `j` are the words in your sentence. 
   Therefore, what the for loop does is iterating over all words in the sentence, with their corresponding position in the senctence.
   If your sentence is "I am answering stack overflow questions", enumerate will yield something like `{0, I}, {1,am}, {2, answering}` and so forth.
2. In python, dictionaries can simply be populated by assigning a value to the dictionary. So this line is what does the trick:

   dictionary[j] = i

   For example, your first iteration will result in the dictionary content `{I:0}` and the second iteration will result in the content `{I:0,am:1}`.
3. Items are added to the list with `list.append(...)`. In this case, values of the dictionary (meaning, the indices `i`!) are added.

I hope this answered your questions. I highly recommend reading about debugging, as stepping through the code will make it easier to understand whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

1. It goes over the elements of splitted: i contains the value of a counter (you could say the index of an element in the list), j contains the next value.
2. This part:

`else:
        dictionary[j]=i
        l.append(i + 1)`

If the word is not yet in the dictionary, the else part is executed and a new key-value pair is inserted in the dictionary

3. See point 2 ;)

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm gives the first occurence of the words of the sentence. You can use index() to get it faster. But if you want to compute all indexes, you should build one list per dictionnary entry :

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence to analyse: ")   
splitted = sentence.split()
dictionary = {}


for i,j in enumerate(splitted,start=1):
    if j in dictionary:
        dictionary[j].append(i)
    else:
        dictionary[j]=[i]


print dictionary
```

You can also use the start option on enumerate if you don t want to start from 0.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think I understood your code, but I wrote another one.
My code uses a dictionary that saves a list of locations of the key letter (run the code if you didn't understand me.

```
sentence = raw_input("Please enter a sentence to analyse: ")
sentence.replace(' ', '') # removing spaces
dictionary = {}
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    if sentence[i] in dictionary:
        dictionary[sentence[i]] += [i]
    else:
        dictionary[sentence[i]] = [i]
print dictionary
```

I hope it helped you. If you still need it to be in a list, please explain again, and maybe this time I will understand.